# VueJS + WebpackSimple not compiling SASS

Tags: webpack, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I have bare new installation of VueJs by webpack simple, trying to set up SASS to CSS. Docs are saying that it is ready for development but webpack only works on SCSS not on SASS. Can some one share some kwnolegde how to use `lang="sass"`?

ALso i followed tutorial on https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass-vs-scss but with no result

**Webpack file**

```
    var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader?indentedSyntax']
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            scss: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            sass: [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

**Error**

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/Group3.png' in 'C:\Users\Damian\Desktop\Vue\karuzela\src'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 7:1073-1101
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js

**Tryinh to wokr on this syntax**

```
.carousel {
  background: url(../img/Group3.png);
  min-height: 350px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 0 0 100px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  **&__row** {
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -100px;
    text-align: left;
    .slick-track {
      padding: 0 0 70px 0;
    }}
```

Comment: vue-style-loader should not be in sass rules. That is first.

Answer (score 1):

Install the sass support first: npm i --save-dev node-sass sass-loader

Comment: please take a look about error after installation node-sass and sass-loader